# JSON_ARRAYAGG returning backslashes when implemented in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, json-arrayagg

I am trying to return multiple array data in JSON but somehow backslashes are coming inside array while implementing in code.
But while running the query in SQL then the data is coming fine as expected.

Node implementation

```
allPackagesByTrip: (id,callBack)=>{
    pool.query(
      `SELECT 'trip_guid', tbl_trip.trip_guid, 'trip_location',tbl_trip.trip_location, 'trip_desc', tbl_trip.trip_desc, 'trip_small_desc', tbl_trip.trip_small_desc, 'trip_rating', tbl_trip.trip_rating,
            
      'tripImage',
             (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                 tbl_trip_image.trip_image_name
             )   
             FROM tbl_trip_image
             WHERE trip_guid = tbl_trip.trip_guid) AS tripImages,
             
             'packages',
             (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                 JSON_OBJECT('packageGuid',tbl_package.pck_guid, 'packageName',tbl_package.pck_name, 'packageStartDate',tbl_package.pck_start_date, 
                 'packageEndDate',tbl_package.pck_end_date, 'packageDays',tbl_package.pck_no_days, 'packageNights', tbl_package.pck_no_night, 'packageShortDesc',tbl_package.pck_short_desc,
                 'packageLongDesc',tbl_package.pck_long_desc, 'packageImageName',tbl_package.pck_image_name)
              )   
             FROM tbl_package
             WHERE trip_guid = tbl_trip.trip_guid) AS packages
             
 FROM tbl_trip
 WHERE tbl_trip.trip_guid = 'e8d21f17-844d-4c7d-b49c-b720282c5ba9'
 AND tbl_trip.status='1'`,
      
     (error,results,fields)=>{
     var resultArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)))
      results = resultArray
         if(error){ 
             return callBack(error)
         }
         return callBack(null,results)
     } 
    )
  }`
```

Json Response
[image]

Expected Result should be that json should be withouth backslashes